# ContextMenu item selection?

Tags: android, textview, contextmenu

I am doing a context menu for various types of manipulation of a music file.But I am not able to get the context menu item selected.In the below code `test4contextmenu` is a class containing `TextView` layout.

```
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
      AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();
      int menuItemIndex = item.getItemId();

      String menuItemName = menuItems[menuItemIndex];
      String songName = songs.get(info.position);

      text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text1);
      text.setText(String.format("Selected %s for item %s", menuItemName, songName));
           startActivity(new Intent(this,test4contextmenu.class));

      return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     private void CreateMenu(Menu menu)
     {
     MenuItem mnu1 = menu.add(0, 0, 0, “Item 1”);
      {
       mnu1.setAlphabeticShortcut(‘a’);
       mnu1.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
      }
     MenuItem mnu2 = menu.add(0, 1, 1, “Item 2”);
      {
       mnu2.setAlphabeticShortcut(‘b’);
       mnu2.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
      }......
       .......
       ........
       ........

      private boolean MenuChoice(MenuItem item)
        {
         switch (item.getItemId()) {
         case 0:
           Toast.makeText(this, “You clicked on Item 1”,
           Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           return true;
         case 1:
           Toast.makeText(this, “You clicked on Item 2”,
           Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           return true;
         case 2:
           Toast.makeText(this, “You clicked on Item 3”,
           Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           return true;           
           }
         ...........
           .............
               ...............
          return false;
         }
```